# Android development of native apps in C# using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, c#-5.0, visual-studio-2015

Microsoft has recently release Visual Studio 2015 preview with Android emulators. My Question is can I use VS2015 to develop Android Applications in C# without using Xamarin.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx

Comment: Thanks @AnikIslamAbhi. So it seems like only C# with Xamarin is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO! What brings .NET and it's languages to Android and iOS is Xamarin.

And Xamarin has Visual Studio integration for some levels of their product.

The Android emulator, is just an emulator. I believe Xamarin also have their own emulators.